# Finding similarity between users in telecomunication network

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, business-intelligence

I've got <s>an anonymous</s> table in which the are two columns: UserId and PhoneNumber.

It was selected from Call Details record table. Now I would like to create a network based on similarity between users. There should be a connection between users if they called to at least 3 the same numbers.

There are more than 20 million rows. When I use a simple program written in C#, it would take more then 4 days to accomplish this task. I wonder, is it possible to write SQL query which would give me the same result and if there is a similarity simply insert a row into a new table with two columns, user1 and user2, or just give it to the output?

Maybe there is some other good solution to accomplish this task?

Comment: Uh. . . are you working for the CIA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is called CallingList, then you should be able to use a query like this:

```
SELECT C1.UserID AS User1, C2.UserID AS User2
  FROM CallingList AS C1
  JOIN CallingList AS C2 ON C1.PhoneNumber = C2.PhoneNumber
 WHERE C1.UserID < C2.UserID
 GROUP BY C1.UserID, C2.UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Whether that will be faster than the C# remains to be seen.

Make sure you have an index on CallingList(PhoneNumber) unless your optimizer will create one automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: Nice Jonathan. Beat me to it. That was what I had too. :-)

Comment: Maybe should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C1.PhoneNumber) >= 3` unless duplicates have already been removed.

Comment: That join would produce roughly... `(20 mln. + 1) × 20 mln. ÷ 2` ≈ 200 trillion rows? It might make sense to first remove those users who called to less than three different numbers.

Comment: @Martin: I was rather assuming that the CallingList was a true table with no duplicate rows in it...I deal with relational databases where that would not even need saying.  In an SQL database, it might be relevant to worry about duplicates; it depends (as you say) on how the calling list is generated.

Comment: @Andriy: there is no cross-product in there so I believe your calculation would only be accurate if there were 20 million users who all called the same one number (and that would only be an intermediate result, since there'd be no records with a count larger than 3).

Comment: @Jonathan: You are right, I should have said, *'might produce...'*. Of course, this is not a pure triangular join, because of the `C1.PhoneNumber = C2.PhoneNumber` condition. However, there still remains a good chance for the result set (albeit intermediate) to be fairly large.

Comment: @Andriy: of course, without knowing the statistics of the data, it is hard to be sure what we might be dealing with. For example, there might be 100K users (each with a phone number) who each made calls to 200 numbers (probably an over-estimate), for 20M records. We might guess that 50% of the calls are to other users in the network, and 50% to other numbers outside. There will be relatively little overlap outside, so there might by 10M out-of-network numbers; the 0.1M in-network numbers don't matter.  Under those assumptions, the result sets are almost certainly entirely manageable.

Comment: @Andriy: a close to optimal query plan would do a merge join using a B-Tree index on (PhoneNumber, UserID).  Whether the optimizer would manage that is perhaps more debatable.